# Access global variable in angular

Tags: javascript, express, angularjs

I am using node express and angular. In my express app.js, I declare a route and pass a variable to the rendered page, like so...

```
app.get('/test' function(req, res){
  res.render('test', { user: 12345 });
});
```

In my 'test' view, I link the container to angular with ng-controller, like so...

```
<div ng-controller='testCtrl'> <!--some markup here--> </div>
```

And in my angular controllers.js, I declare a function for my view, like so...

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
    /*...some code here...*/
}
```

How can I access the 'user' variable that I passed in to the view from express, inside my controller function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're using a template to render a view, there are two different executions: (1) your server is rendering a page (using the `user` var) and then (2) the browser runs AngularJS. So you can't pass a variable from (1) into (2).

However, there is a directive called [`ngInit`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) that will parse an expression during bootstrap. If you're using Jade templates in ExpressJS, you could do something like this:

```jade
div(ng-init='user = "'+user+'"')
```

Which would render the HTML like so:

```html
<div ng-init="user = 'whatever-server-sent'"></div>
```

So when AngularJS bootstraps this part of the page (or this partial or template) then `user` will become a scope variable with the value from the server.

I didn't test the Jade code and I'm not a Jade expert, but this should put you on the right track. If you're using a different templating engine, let me know and I'll revise the answer.

Comment: Thanks Josh, a great help indeed and +1 for identifying the root of my confusion :)

Answer (score -1):

Jade variables can be accessed in Angular by assigning interpolated value to a variable in `ng-init`

First you have to stringify the user and then interpolate using `#{value}
div(ng-init = 'angularUser = #{JSON.stringify(user)}')`

In this situation the `user` variable is a Jade variable

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to help you write and format your answer.